# How to differentiate when an Angular component is loaded via template or a route?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to tell how a component was loaded by Angular - I have a component that can be accessed via a route or loaded via another component's template and I'd like to be able to detect how the component was loaded for animation purposes.

Comment: You can use an @Input on this component and set it to a different value depending on where you use it in your project.

Comment: Did you solve this without input or data trick?

Comment: I used the @Input method, but I haven't accepted Umar's answer because I'm holding out for something more purposeful (e.g. an Angular feature specifically intended to signal how the component was instantiated) - but given the lack of additional feedback on this question perhaps Umar's approaches are the only/best ways to make this determination...

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you two tricks one them either work use an input to your component and if it is loaded via selector you will get the input but not via router.

Second option is pass the data to component via `data` property in router and extract that in component constructor you got it means component is loaded from route else not.

If you've problem with router data then you have only option to detect route and aplly your logic

For router data resolving look into this
https://www.google.ca/amp/s/yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/amp/

Comment: do you know a better way? @input or route data are kind of tricks! maybe there is a flag somewhere.